# Prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{a^2-ab+b^2}\geq\sqrt[3]{\sum\limits_{cyc}(8a^2+bc)}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative numbers. Prove that:
$$\sqrt[3]{a^2-ab+b^2}+\sqrt[3]{a^2-ac+c^2}+\sqrt[3]{b^2-bc+c^2}\geq\sqrt[3]{8(a^2+b^2+c^2)+ab+ac+bc}$$

Let $a=\max\{a,b,c\}$.

Hence, the estimation $\sqrt[3]{a^2-ab+b^2}+\sqrt[3]{a^2-ac+c^2}\geq\sqrt[3]{2(3a^2+(b+c-a)^2)}$

gives a proof, but it's very ugly.

Is there something nice? Thank you!